# Scale down screen, instead of scaling up

Tags: display, resolution

I have a Dell Latitude E6430, which has 1600x900 screen. However, I'd like to scale everything down, so that the OS "sees" a 1920x1080 display instead. Is anything like this possible on Windows 10?

Answer (score -1):

You cam change your screen resolution to 1920x1080 by right clicking on your desktop and choosing "display settings". Scroll to the bottem and choose "Advanced display settings".  Here you can select your resolution.

Comment: The OP is asking about display scaling, *NOT* how to change the resolution. Please re-read the question and [edit] your answer to be a better fit.